# classless IP Subnetting

Tags: networking, subnet

i want to do subnetting with the given ip address as follows
192.168.10.0/25
My requirement is i want 30 addresses per subnet.
what will be the nw address of subnet 0?
is it 192.168.10.0/27 or 192.168.10.128/27 ?

Answer (score 0):

The [ipcalc](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.10.0&mask1=25&mask2=27) tool can answer this for you:

```
Address:   192.168.10.0          11000000.10101000.00001010.0 0000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.128 = 25  11111111.11111111.11111111.1 0000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.127             00000000.00000000.00000000.0 1111111
=>
Network:   192.168.10.0/25       11000000.10101000.00001010.0 0000000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 192.168.10.127        11000000.10101000.00001010.0 1111111
HostMin:   192.168.10.1          11000000.10101000.00001010.0 0000001
HostMax:   192.168.10.126        11000000.10101000.00001010.0 1111110
Hosts/Net: 126                   (Private Internet)


Subnets

Netmask:   255.255.255.224 = 27  11111111.11111111.11111111.111 00000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.31              00000000.00000000.00000000.000 11111

Network:   192.168.10.0/27       11000000.10101000.00001010.000 00000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 192.168.10.31         11000000.10101000.00001010.000 11111
HostMin:   192.168.10.1          11000000.10101000.00001010.000 00001
HostMax:   192.168.10.30         11000000.10101000.00001010.000 11110
Hosts/Net: 30                    (Private Internet)


Network:   192.168.10.32/27      11000000.10101000.00001010.001 00000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 192.168.10.63         11000000.10101000.00001010.001 11111
HostMin:   192.168.10.33         11000000.10101000.00001010.001 00001
HostMax:   192.168.10.62         11000000.10101000.00001010.001 11110
Hosts/Net: 30                    (Private Internet)


Network:   192.168.10.64/27      11000000.10101000.00001010.010 00000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 192.168.10.95         11000000.10101000.00001010.010 11111
HostMin:   192.168.10.65         11000000.10101000.00001010.010 00001
HostMax:   192.168.10.94         11000000.10101000.00001010.010 11110
Hosts/Net: 30                    (Private Internet)


Network:   192.168.10.96/27      11000000.10101000.00001010.011 00000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 192.168.10.127        11000000.10101000.00001010.011 11111
HostMin:   192.168.10.97         11000000.10101000.00001010.011 00001
HostMax:   192.168.10.126        11000000.10101000.00001010.011 11110
Hosts/Net: 30                    (Private Internet)



Subnets:   4 
Hosts:     120
```

Also, the address `192.168.10.128` is beyond the range of the original `/25`!